# When trying to save a vector in QGIS a blank dropdown window appears

Tags: qgis, vector

I am learning and using QGIS Brighton and have hit a obstacle. Everything has been going fine until I started using the experimental generalizer to smooth the contours that I had extracted from some DEM's but it may be something else.

When I create a vector, it all works well until I right click to save. I get a blank dropdown screen. I uninstalled generalizer and then QGIS did a reinstall to no avail. Several times. This blank drop down is starting to apply to other menus (contour extraction, attribute table,   qgis-bin etc.) it is a little bit annoying as you can imagine. Any ideas in how to resolve?

Comment: Think I may have solved it.  Did a clean reinstall deleting .qgis2  from users menu,  qgis folder from C. Deleted qgis remnants  from registry. Then found out about disappearing toolbars from manual so removed registry key ( ...\QGIS\UI\state) reinstalled QGIS then went into settings /options /system / Qsettings and reset  the user interface to default settings. Chug chug! Back in action.